# A Confusing Comment-Program

Tags: wordplay

Prof. Pheno Menon has developed a artificial intelligence program which he calls "The Phenomenal Commentator". That day he called on me to give a demo of his phenomenal creation.

"Here," he explained, "in the input box, you need to enter a literary extract, and *the program closely inspects it, letter by letter, and finally generates a erudite comment* on its quality, meaning et cetera."

"Wow, that's interesting! Can I try it?" I asked.

"Sure", he replied, "but not more than five instances. It takes a huge amount of computational time."

I wasn't in the mood to type up five novels or verses, so I just thought of *five well-known proverbs or quotes* and fed them into it, one at a time. These are the replies it came up with:

1. > An exciting text phrases candid hate-tone.
2. > Words worth noting; make tag.
3. > I'd find a refined, dense inner idea.
4. > The best riot-quotation, to be honest.
5. > Then, sir, the belief's great, fine.

I said, "Not really impressive, Professor. It just seems to cook up random, irrelevant sentences, which somewhat sound like literary comments."

He beamed at me. "My son, you know my creations. *The comments it generates have a brilliant and close relation with the respective inputs.* 50 dollars if you can find out the relation."

Now, I don't remember the sentences I typed in, except that one of them was "**A friend in need is a friend indeed.**". Can you help me remember the other sentences and find out the connection?

---

### Note:

1. No computer-knowledge is necessary to solve this puzzle.
2. A correct solution must consist of the five sentences, the indication of which sentence corresponds to which output, and the relation between an input and its output (which should be obvious by then).
3. All those five comments are (mostly) hand-crafted. I am not sure if such a program can be even created.

Comment: Should post this on the [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) exchange to see if they can make a program to create the comments you have made here. haha :P

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The relation between the inputs and the outputs is that they are

> Anagrams of each other

1. An exciting text phrases candid hate-tone.

> Nothing is certain except death and taxes (Thanks [@sconibulus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/40550/12914)!)

2. Words worth noting; make tag.

> Two wrongs don't make a right.

3. I'd find a refined, dense inner idea.

> A friend in need is a friend indeed.

4. The best riot-quotation, to be honest.

> To be or not to be, that is the question.

5. Then, sir, the belief's great, fine.

> The best things in life are free

Comment: Excellent and super-quick! Only one remaining...

Comment: Yeah, and I'm having so much trouble with it. I will get it eventually!

Answer (score 13):

The first one is:

> Nothing is certain except death and taxes